# How can I install my requirements.txt file when someone installs my python package via pip?

Tags: python

I  had a python package I build that used pretty standard libraries like requests, etc..

I added a new dependency that is not standard so it needs to be installed as part of my library.

I have a requirements.txt file in my pip package but I am not sure how to actually call it so when someone pip installs my_package, it also gets my requirements as well.

I've seen this before, where I pip to install a library then it installs pandas or another dependency as well. I'm not sure how to do this, I reviewed the documentation on building modules but it's not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option is not to use `requirements.txt` but instead to specify the dependencies inside `setup.py` in the `install_requires` section. For example:

```
setup(
    name = 'mypkg',
    install_requires = [
      dependency,
      other-dependency,
      third-dependency>=4.3,
    ],
)
```

If you're used to using `requirements.txt` during development, you can install the dependencies from your package into a virtualenv by instead running:

```
pip install -e .
```